# How to set the DataContext of a View in XAML with a ViewModel which needs the View as Parameter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create the `ViewModel` of my WPF Application in the XAML code.
It's easy if you just have the default constructor, but I need the `View` as a Parameter, so I have to call the `Constructor` myself.

This is as far as I came:

```
<ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type local:ViewModel}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
        <Binding Source="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
    </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

But with this there is an `TargetInvocationException` thrown, because `ConstrutorParameter` doesn't accept `Binding`:

> "Binding" can not be used within a ParameterCollection collection.
>   "Binding" can only be set on a "DependencyProperty" of a
>   "DependencyObject".

Is there any way to convert "Self" to an object or something?

Comment: Are you trying to bind your viewmodel to view using a static resource?

Comment: The [RelativeSource.Self](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.self(v=vs.100).aspx) is a static resource.

Comment: Passing the view into the view model sounds like a really **really** bad idea. Why does your view model need to know about the view?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seem to be the right context. I didn't ask for MVVM best practice or something. ATM I'm just using it for some debug purposes. I think I could do all the stuff without the View, but the question is, if it is possible to write something like `DataContext = new ViewModel(this);` (`this` is the View) in XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self already points to an object. Your problem in this case is that ParameterCollection isn't a DependencyObject, i.e. it is not derived from the DependencyObject class and does not implement its properties as DependencyProperties as per the DependencyObject implementation convention, just as the error message suggests.
To work around this, you could wrap the class ObjectDataProvider into a wrapper class that implements DependencyObject and takes the values you give here as constructor parameters as DependencyProperties. Then you could pass "self" or any other resource to one of these properties and initialize the ObjectDataProvider inside your wrapper, passing the value of the property to the constructor of ObjectDataProvider.

```
class ObjectDataProviderWrapper : DependencyObject {
    private ObjectDataProvider _objectDataProvider = null;
    public static DependencyProperty ControlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(.... (look that up in the manual, it depends on your use case)

    public ObjectDataProvider DataProvider {
        get {
            if(_objectDataProvider == null) {
                _objectDataProvider = new ObjectDataProvider(ControlProperty.GetValue(this));
             }
            return _objectDataProvider;
        }
    }
....
```

Using the ObjectDataProvider later on in your Xaml then would require one additional level of indirection, i.e. you will have to dereference your wrapper, which could be done using a DataContext scope like for example:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource wrapper}, Path=DataProvider}" >
...
</Grid>
```

Comment: I think I understand your idea and implemented it. But now I have another Problem: I instantiate the wrapper in `Grid.Resources`, but it cannot find the `Grid` to set it as Parameter. I tryed to it find by `Ancestor` and by `ElementName`. Seems the `Grid` isn't created before ist Resources: `<l:ObjectDataProviderWrapper x:Key="wrapper" ConstructorParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}" ObjectType="{x:Type l:ViewModel}"/>`

Comment: Yes, because your "wrapper" Instance is being created *before* it is added to the collection of resources, it won't find any surrounding objects at that time. You can only bind to objects that are accessible before your wrapper is instantiated. Maybe you can try to NOT add it to a resource dictionary, but to the XAML tree as a component, the reference it by ElementName or similar. Or make it into a component that provides a DataContext itself for child components, and put all other visual elements that need access to the DataProvider into it.

Comment: OK, I derived from UIElement, so I can put it somewhere in the XAML. The Binding is all done by `ElementName`. The Wrapper will be created, but it seems it doesn't do any Binding. I set breakpoints in the setter and getter of the DPs, but non of them were hitten. So the Program runs without any Errors, but doesn't create the `ViewModel` or bind it to the `View`. I don't know what's wrong...

Comment: Hard to diagnose it this way... There could be many reasons. Are you sure your binding is two-way? Is your DependencyProperty registered with the correct parameters? ...